# Plugin retrieving results even after uninstallation

Tags: plugins, rest-api, uninstallation

I'm using the [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/) plugin to get info from my website. I built a little plugin that uses this one. In my plugin I'm just removing some fields from the responses that I don't need.

Everything was working well until some hours ago the filter by category I was applying when requesting the categories stopped working. It started retrieving all posts.

I tried on an HTTP Request tool (POSTMAN) invoking the WP REST API and it doesn't filter too. My request URL is like this:

http://my.domain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true&filter[cat]=77

But if I try:

http://my.domain/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed=true&categories=77

It works.

So I deactivated (and even uninstalled) the WP REST API plugin, made the request and it was still retrieving me the posts!

I have 2 questions:

- Why is an uninstalled plugin still retrieving results?
- Is it possible another plugin to be the responsible for retrieving the results? I checked the active plugins for another that could do something like this but didn't find anything...

I'm new using Wordpress so probably  I'm not aware of something...

**UPDATE**

Wordpress version: 4.7

Comment: What version of WordPress is installed?

Comment: @DaveRomsey It's 4.7.

Comment: Thought that might be the case. WP 4.7 added the REST API into core. I don't have a solid answer, but wanted to clear that up.

Comment: @DaveRomsey That explains why I was getting results even after disabling the plugin... It seems that is not fully compatible. But I think you found the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WordPress v4.7](https://wordpress.org/news/2016/12/vaughan/) has added the REST API into core, so this might explain why your REST functionality is still available even after uninstalling the REST API plugin.

Comment: This WordPress v4.7 video you referenced looks so impressive, like programmers are no longer needed...

Comment: I guess from now on if the project leader is feminine, the WP Jazz name will also be.